# jquery move an item in object from one position to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got and object of objects like this:

```
var obj = {

    0:{id: 1, name: 'one'},
    1:{id: 2, name: 'two'},
    2:{id: 3, name: 'three'},
    3:{id: 4, name: 'four'}
};
```

I need to move an item under the key 1 from its current position to position 4 (where an item with `id: 4` is), so it should look like the following:

```
var obj = {

    0:{id: 1, name: 'one'},
    1:{id: 3, name: 'three'},
    2:{id: 4, name: 'four'},
    3:{id: 2, name: 'two'},
};
```

The problem is that it is an object of objects, not an array. If it were an array I could do it with the help of the following function:

```
function array_move(arr, old_index, new_index) {
    if (new_index >= arr.length) {
        var k = new_index - arr.length + 1;
        while (k--) {
            arr.push(undefined);
        }
    }
    arr.splice(new_index, 0, arr.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);             
  };
```

But in this case I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: arr.splice is not a function
```

Any ideas how to fix it would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: do you need to use an object of objects? Any reason why you can't use an array of objects?

Comment: Yes, it comes from some legacy code. And moreover, I need to preserve keys in the object

Comment: you can then if `arr` is an array or object, if it is object, you can use `arr = Object.values(arr)`, to get an array with just the values, in this case, an array containing the objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of keys and values and then order them:

```
var keys = Object.keys(obj);
var values = Object.values(obj);
var newObj = {};

values = array_move(values);

keys.forEach(function(el, i){
   newObj[el] = values[i]; 
});
```